# bash script to compile and run test cases

Tags: c++, bash

Completely new to bash scripts, trying to make a script to compile and run all cpp files that start with "blah". What I have so far is

```
#1/bin/bash

for i in blah*.cpp 
do
    if g++ "$i" -o "${i%.cpp}.out"; then
        /Users/[directory]/Desktop/"${i%.cpp}.out" #to run each testcase

    else
        echo "failed"
    fi
done
```

I need to know how many blah files succeeded in running (I can either make the c++ programs return 1 or just cout "succeeded", any way to tell would be fine), and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the return status of each program or how to use the output from each program run and see if it says "succeeded".

Comment: Instead of `/Users/[directory]/Desktop/` why not just use `./`?

Comment: `~/Desktop`? `$HOME/Desktop`?`

Answer (score 0):

Have your test case return 1 for success and 0 for failure. The return value can then be used as follows:

```
counter=0
for i in blah*.cpp 
do
    if g++ "$i" -o "${i%.cpp}.out"; then
        if  /Users/[directory]/Desktop/"${i%.cpp}.out" ; then
            counter=$((counter+1))
        else
           echo "failed to run"
        fi
    else
        echo "failed to build"
    fi
done
echo "$counter tests succeeded"
```